# How to typeset \substack without shrinking the text size

Tags: math-mode

So, how to typeset the next (stuff inside red outline):
[image]

It have to be like `\substack` but with normal font size.

Comment: Please, what is your minimal working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? Your question it is not more clear.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}
\[\int\limits_{\alpha=0}^{\beta=\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{6\tan x \, dx}{3\sin\alpha x+5\cos^2x}=\begin{vmatrix} t=\tan \alpha & dx=\dfrac{2dt}{1+t^2}\\
\sin x=\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2} & \\
\alpha=0, & \beta=\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt 2}}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2}}
\end{vmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Damn, how I could forget a bout matrix enviroment. Thank You!